# Can I connect a two-wire remote controlled fan to separate light and fan switch wiring?

Tags: wiring

I have a ceiling fan installed with the use of a dual-gang box, with one switch controlling the fan and the other controlling the light. We are shopping around for new fans and are seeing many fans we like but they are remote-controlled and they only come with 2 wires from the fan (Black and White). Is it still possible to wire these fans up with dual gang control boxes?

Comment: Do the fans you're looking at say they have a "DC motor" on them?

Comment: No it is not possible. Only remote can switch between fan and light or both

Comment: However, if you insist, you could bypass the remote and use your switches.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at how the fans are set up.  Remote control modules up at the fan are "all the rage" because they cheapen the fan's manufacturing, thus making the price more attractive.   However most remote control setups allow you to "swing either way" - either have the remote control just the fan, or the fan+light.

In the case of "just the fan", the light power line bypasses the remote control and is directly driven by the switched-hot for the light.

Note that Code requires each habitable room to have a light switch *that works*. It must operate a light, or a receptacle (in which a lamp would be plugged in).